# How to listen keyup events outside any input on iOS with Ionic 3

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, events, keyup

My problem is quite simple, and I think I know the answer, but if I'm wrong it could be great …
I would like to use an external barcode scanner (work like a physical bluetooth keyboard) to read barcodes but outside any input.
I made a piece of code which works great on android devices but nothing happend on iOS devices …
I'll make it quick, I listen «keyup» events on «window» and when I catch the «Enter» key, I emit the barcode event …
I use RxJS and Observable fromEvent and everithing works great on Android devices.

Is the Safari WebView the problem ?
I remember I already had the same issue on website, Safari does not trigger keyboard events outside elements which don't require keyboard (input, textarea …)

```
/**
 * Outil pour traiter la lecture d'un codebarre par un lecteur physique
 * Seuls les évènements claviers hors input sont récupérés
 */
export namespace LecteurCodebarrePhysique {
    // L'évènement est-il dans un input ?
    const inInput = (event) => {return event.target instanceof Element && event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'input'};
    // La touche relachée est-elle un caractère ?
    const isTextKey = (event) => {return !inInput(event) && event.key.length === 1};
    // La touche relachée est-elle la touche entrée ?
    const isEnter = (event) => {return !inInput(event) && event.keyCode === 13};

    /**
     * Observable émettant le codebarre lu par un lecteur physique
     */
    export function codebarreLu(): Observable<{text: string, format: string}> {
        // Observable initiale : évèrement clavier
        const keyup: Observable<KeyboardEvent> = fromEvent(window, 'keyup');
        return keyup.pipe(
            // On ne garde que les touches représentant un caractère
            filter(ev => isTextKey(ev)),
            // On ne garde que la valeur du caractère
            map(ev => ev.key),
            // On «bufferise» en attendant la touche entrée
            buffer(keyup.pipe(filter(ev => {
                const enter = isEnter(ev);
                if (enter) {
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    ev.stopPropagation();
                }
                return enter;
            }))),
            // Quand la touche entrée est relachée, on concatène les caractères
            // Et on essaye de déterminer si c'es un EAN13 (13 caractères numériques)
            map(chars => {
                const codebarre = chars.reduce((code, char) => code + char, '');
                const isEan13 = /\d{13}/.test(codebarre);
                return {text: codebarre, format: isEan13 ? 'EAN_13' : 'INCONNU'};
            })
        );
    }
}
```

On Android devices, if I subscribe to the observable and read a barcode outside any inputs, the code inside the subscription is called.
On iOS devices, nothing happend …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka!
If other guys have the same issue/need of me, I post here the answer! Yes I'm too kind ^^
I've changed the target of the event from «window» to «document» and … wait for it … It works.